# Is there a way in Powershell to not search in multiple folders

Tags: powershell, file, search

I want to search for all files in a PC but I want to exclude some of the folders.
I'm currently using `Where-Object { ($_.FullName -notmatch $excludepath)` but the problem with this is it looks up in those paths and then filters it. I want my program to not look up in some paths at all because it takes up a lot of time!

Edit: This is the code I'm working with. I want to search a PC for either all the files or with some specific filters like files with specific name, extension and also give the option to exclude a path entirely. This code does all that but while excluding a path it searches in the path and then filters out using `Where-Object { ($_.FullName -notmatch $excludepath)` . Because C drive is so big I want my program to not look up in the certain multiple path mentioned rather than searching in them and then  filtering.

```
$Filename   = "img"
$IncludeExt =  "*.jpeg"
$excludepath = "^C:\\Windows" ,"^C:\\Program Files"

$GCIArgs = @{Path    = $Drives.Root
             Recurse = $True
             }

If ($Null -ne $IncludeExt) {
  $GCIArgs.Add("Include",$IncludeExt)
}

Get-ChildItem @GCIArgs | Where-Object { ($_.FullName -notmatch $excludepath) -and ($Ignore -notcontains $_.Extension) -and ($_.BaseName -match $Filename )} |

foreach{ 
$Item = $_.Basename
$Path = $_.FullName 
$Type = $_.Extension
$Modified=$_.LastWriteTime
$Age = $_.CreationTime
$Type = &{if($_.PSIsContainer){"Folder"}else{$_.Extension}}



$Path | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={$Item}},        
                      @{n="Created";e={$Age}},
                      @{n="filePath";e={$Path}},
                
                      @{n="Modified";e={$Modified}},
                      @{n="Folder/File";e={$Type}}  

}| Export-Csv D:\SF.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Which paths? Maybe show you current code and describe what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

try trhis:

```
$dirtoexclude=@(
'C:\temp\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\svnkit\licenses', 
'C:\temp\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\lib' , 
'C:\temp\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\extensions\oracle.olap',
'C:\temp\sqldeveloper'
)

#method 1 : if you want exclude specific directory
get-childitem "c:\temp" -Recurse | where DirectoryName -notin $dirtoexclude

#method 2 : if you want exclude specific directory and sub directory
get-childitem "c:\temp" -Recurse | foreach{

$Current=$_

#search if current directory element start by one of directory to exclude
$founded=$dirtoexclude | where {$Current.DirectoryName -like "$_*"} | select * -First 1

#not start by directory to exclude, send element to output    
if (!$founded)
{
   $Current
}

}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the solution but can you tell me what is happening in the code you gave and how can I integrate it into my program. I'm a beginner in powershell so I can't really understand what is happening!

Comment: I'm relatively new to powershell too but I've quickly been able to get up to speed by using the resources listed on [Powershell learning resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/more-powershell-learning?view=powershell-7.1).  I'd start with the [videos on channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Getting-Started-with-Microsoft-PowerShell)